# Parse Push Never Sent

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

So, I'm testing Parse.com to handle push notification for my application. I have the following Installations data:

[image: installation data]

These are installations from two users. The problem is, whenever I try to push from website, parse never sent any single push to device.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

As shown above, 0 pushes sent. I am not sure what went wrong. Maybe you guys can shed some light, here?

Comment: are your users subscribed to a channel?

Comment: No they are not. The end goal is for me to send different push message to different installation. So, there's no need to use channel.

Comment: They can still be set to the default Broadcast channel and you can just query the for certain users when you send pushes

Comment: problem is, even if the push is set for all devices, no single push get sent :(